# Does Jinja support variable assignment as a result of a loop?

Tags: jinja2

I've been using Jinja and DBT for a month now, and despite reading a lot about it, I didn't quite figure out how to create a list from another, using a simple for loop like I would in Python.
Just a toy example:

```
{%- set not_wanted_columns = ['apple', 'banana'] -%} 
{%- set all_columns = ['kiwi', 'peach', 'apple', 'banana', 'apricot', 'pineapple'] -%}
```

What I want is a list as so:

```
{% set filtered_columns = ['kiwi', 'peach', 'apricot', 'pineapple'] %}
```

Naturally, I don't want to manually write this result because the full list might be dynamic or too long. I'm not even sure if Jinja does actually support this, although I do think this is a common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have probably read from the documentation:

> Please note that assignments in loops will be cleared at the end of the iteration and cannot outlive the loop scope. Older versions of Jinja had a bug where in some circumstances it appeared that assignments would work. This is not supported.

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#for*</sup>

And I guess when you are speaking about

> using a simple for loop like I would in Python

What you mean here is using a [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-and-similar-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i).

So, as showed in the documentation, Jinja is using filter to achieve this:

> Example usage:
>
> ```
> {{ numbers|select("odd") }} 
> {{ numbers|select("divisibleby", 3) }}
> ```
>
> Similar to a generator comprehension such as:
>
> ```py
> (n for n in numbers if test_odd(n))
> (n for n in numbers if test_divisibleby(n, 3))
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.select*</sup>

There are actual four of those filter acting as generator comprehension:

- [`reject`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.reject)
- [`rejectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.rejectattr)
- [`select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.select)
- [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr)

---

So, in your case, a `reject` filter would totally do the trick:

```
{%- set filtered_columns = all_columns
     | reject('in', not_wanted_columns) 
     | list 
-%}
```

---

But, if you really want, you could also achieve it in a `for`:

```
{%- for column in all_columns if column not in not_wanted_columns -%}
  {% do filtered_columns.append(column) %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

The `do` statement being a way to use `list.append()` without oddities being printed out: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#expression-statement.

Comment: Nice! I had just experimented with the reject and made something akin to it, however, I don't quite understand the reason for the last pipe for list, given that we already start with a list.

Comment: In some versions of Jinja the filter like `select`, `reject`, `map`, make you end up with a generator object, and you have to cast it back as a list. You do not have to do it in recent version anymore, though.